# Jquery function to Increment one hours based on time input string

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime-format

I have string value in this format.

```
9:00 am
```

i want it to be like this.

```
9:00 am - 10:00 am
```

second hour must be 1 greater then first one. for example if time is

```
7:00 am then it should be 7:00 am - 8:00 am
```

how can i do that using jquery?
i tried this but its not working as it works now.

```
var time= "9:00 am"
var nexttime=time.setHours(time.getHours()+1)
 alert(nexttime);
```

getting error of

```
time.getHours is not a function
```

Comment: And why is this question tagged with PHP? No relation to it.

Comment: because after adding one hour in it i want to match it with same string in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
function increaseTimeByOne(timeStr) {
    var splitedTimeStr = timeStr.split(':');
    var hours = parseInt(splitedTimeStr[0]);
    var meridiem = splitedTimeStr[1].split(" ")[1];
    var minutes = splitedTimeStr[1].split(" ")[0];
    var nextHours = (hours + 1);
    var nextMeridiem;
    if (hours >= 11) {
        if (meridiem.toLowerCase() == "am") {
            nextMeridiem = "pm";
        } else if (meridiem.toLowerCase() == "pm") {
            nextMeridiem = "am";
        }
        if (nextHours > 12) {
            nextHours = nextHours - 12;
        }

    } else {
        nextMeridiem = meridiem;
    }
    return nextHours + ":" + minutes + " " + nextMeridiem;
}
```

and using above function as

```
var timestr="9:00 am";
var next_hour = increaseTimeByOne(timeStr);
alert(next_hour);
```

Comment: your answer seems to be good but i am getting only 10 in alert. 
i want "10:00 am"

Comment: @shahidhamdam  can you pls check it now and update the status

Comment: sir the answer you have given is working great for am times. but if i select 1:00 pm it shows me 1:00 pm - 2:00 am. can you suggest something?

Comment: @shahidhamdam can you pls check it now

Comment: if i select 5:00 pm it show me 6:00 am. i need it to show me 6:00 pm.

Comment: it gives me 12:00 pm only if i select 11:00 am

Comment: @shahid hamdam if 11:00 am + 1 hr is 12 pm right... you want it to be zeo..Uh..?

Comment: @samuelj90 Your answer works perfectly for me in the "12 hours" time format but can you please suggest how to add one hour in the "24 hours" time format?

Comment: @Mansi. This question is intended only for 12 hr time format with HH:MM (AM/PM) a similar question with your request below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530000/add-hours-in-12-hour-format-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1):

refer this

```
var time=new Date();        
time.setHours(9, 00, 00);
var nexttime=(time.getHours()+1);
alert(nexttime);
```

// to get hrs mins and seconds

```
var nexttime=(time.getHours()+1) +":"+time.getMinutes()+":"+time.getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu can make your time string like:

```js
function increaseTimeByOne(t) {
  var s  = t.split(':');
  var n  = parseInt(s[0], 10);
  var nt = (n + 1) + ":00 ";   
  var ampm = n >= 11 ? "pm" : "am";

  return t + " - " + nt + ampm;
}

console.log(increaseTimeByOne('9:00 am'));
console.log(increaseTimeByOne('11:00 am'));
console.log(increaseTimeByOne('12:00 pm'));
```